# How do you prevent React from resetting the scroll position when a component is re-rendered?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The example below is a bit contrived but it illustrates the point. Instead of using Data Grid's built-in column filter (i.e. the popup that appears when you click the "Columns" button), I'm using a custom one. Whenever I scroll to the bottom of this custom popup, and check/uncheck something, the scrollbar jumps to the top of the popup. How can I prevent this from happening in the first place? Or is there a way to restore the scrollbar position after re-render?

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollbar-issue-045n82)

Comment: You couldn't prevent that suppose you have 10 data you scroll down to the bottom of the page then after checking or unchecking filter the data result of the data 5 then scroll move to the top because you didn't have 10 data after applying the filter

Comment: @MeetMajevadiya, thanks for your comment. The number of columns displayed shouldn't change when a column is checked/unchecked, so the issue you brought up shouldn't be a problem in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
components={{
  Toolbar: GridToolbar,
  ColumnsPanel: () => (
    <ColumnFilter columns={columns} setColumns={setColumns} />
  )
}}
```

Each time `columns` changes, the ColumnFilter is recreated.

The solution is to instead pass the props to the component using Data Grid's `componentsProp` prop like so:

```
components={{
  Toolbar: GridToolbar,
  ColumnsPanel: ColumnFilter
}}
componentsProps={{
  columnsPanel: {
    columns,
    setColumns
  }
}}
```

See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollbar-issue-resolved-xgvzwi?file=/DataGridDemo.js:377-402) for a working example.